# AKKA Streams: Performance degradation after connecting to AMQP

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have been trying to create an application that runs recursive task (crawler) with akka streams and QPID message broker.
What I have noticed is that separate parts of the graph alone perform quite good, but when connected together performance drops down significantly.
Here is statistics for the graph running on my local machine:

- sending messages to message queue can achieve > 1700 msg/sec;
- making HTTP requests approx. 70 req/sec;
- whole graph, including reading
  messages from queue 2-4 items/sec;

Source code for the pipeline can be found here: 
https://gist.github.com/volisoft/3617824b16a3f3b6e01c933a8bdf8049

The pipeline is straightforward:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  startBroker()

  val queueName = "amqp-conn-it-spec-simple-queue-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
  val queueDeclaration = QueueDeclaration(queueName)

  val in = AmqpSource(
    NamedQueueSourceSettings(AmqpConnectionDetails("localhost", 5672, Some(AmqpCredentials("guest", "guest"))), queueName)
      .withDeclarations(queueDeclaration),
    bufferSize = 1028
  ).map(_.bytes.utf8String).log(":in")

  val out = AmqpSink.simple(
    AmqpSinkSettings(AmqpConnectionDetails("localhost", 5672, Some(AmqpCredentials("guest", "guest"))))
      .withRoutingKey(queueName).withDeclarations(queueDeclaration))

  val urlsSink = Flow[String].map(ByteString(_)).to(out)

  val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(in, urlsSink)((_,_)){ implicit b => (in, urlsSink0) =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val pool = Http().superPool[String]()(materializer).log(":pool")
    val download: Flow[String, Document, NotUsed] = Flow[String]
      .map(url => (HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET, Uri(url)), url) )
      .via(pool)
      .mapAsyncUnordered(8){ case (Success(response: HttpResponse), url) => parse(response, url)}

    val filter = Flow[String].filter(notVisited).log(":filter")
    val save = Flow[String].map(saveVisited)

    val extractLinks: Flow[Document, String, NotUsed] = Flow[Document].mapConcat(document => getUrls(document))


    in ~> save ~> download ~> extractLinks ~> filter ~> urlsSink0


    ClosedShape
  })

  g.run()

  Source.single(rootUrl).map(s => ByteString(s)).runWith(out)
}
```

How can this code be optimized to increase performance?